# Startup script for spawn-fcgi

Tags: services, upstart

I would like to use spawn-fcgi to start a web.py application on system boot. Is there any facility for managing spawn-fcgi through Upstart? (Is Upstart the modern system for managing services, or should I be looking somewhere else?)

Answer (score 0):

Upstart is the system for managing services in Ubuntu. I don't know the specifics for spawn-fcgi. For quick start on getting something running, read [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96011/running-commands-on-boot-in-11-10/97770#97770). Dig into subject by reading [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/), which is the absolute authority in Upstart documentation.

Comment: I need one help.. I have a 3 vm's in my machine. I want to start the 3 vm's while starting the machine. How to do in startup script